# is it possible to get the Entity object before objectify saves it (and fill some other data)

Tags: objectify

I have some personal data structure mixed with "standard fields". I would like to avoid the manual work on simple fields (with datastore native API):

```
toPersist.setProperty("field1", value1);
toPersist.setUnindexedProperty("field2", value2);
```

but I still want to get the prefilled Entity instance `toPersist` so I can add my own `@Ignore` fields my self

For example:

```
Entity filled = OfyService.ofy().save().entity(this).fill();
filled.setProperty("mySpecialField", jsonValue);
//...
// I want to save my entities alone
datastore.put( filled );
```

reversely I'd like to get the Entity object representing each entry in a `load()` call.

Is this possible? or do I have to dive into Objectify code to hack it?

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't follow your question exactly, but I'm pretty sure what you're looking for are the `@OnLoad` and `@OnSave` annotations.  You add them to methods within your entity classes, and those methods will be called just after an entity is loaded, or just before one is saved, respectively.  The documentation for them is [here](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/LifecycleCallbacks).

**Edit**:
After your comments (below) I now understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Yes, Objectify supports this (though I have never tried it myself).  You want to use the `Saver.toEntity()` and `Loader.fromEntity()` methods.  It appears you can use them like this:

```
// Use Objectify to convert a POJO into an Entity
Entity filled = ofy().save().toEntity(myPojo);

// Use Objectify to convert an Entity into a POJO
Object pojoCopy = ofy().load().fromEntity(filled);
```

Comment: Hi @Eric Simonton,
Your answer is partially answering: I want to save my Entity instances alone through the native API since I add some dynamic columns depending on the Entity state. So I want Objectify to  populate an Entity instance with regular field, then pass it to me so I can add my own fields and save it by my self

Comment: The job that Objectify does is valuable (escape *Ignore fields, use *Index to recognize indexed fields, skip nulls etc...). I want to have that part, but without the rest (I want to save and load alone through native APIs)

Comment: @ZiedHamdi Oh I see!  Sorry for the confusion.  See my edit above.

Comment: Thanks Eric,
This is exactly what I was searching for :)

Comment: Hi Eric, I have a new issue now: since I persist my objects through datastore.persist(), the Objectify cache won't get notified of the object data change. It seams there's no good way to reset the cache in objectify if I believe this dicussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/objectify-appengine/n3FJjnYVVsk/6Xp99zReOKQJ

Comment: @ZiedHamdi Since I've never used Objectify this way, I'm not sure when/if it hits the cache.  I would think that you don't want Objectify to do any caching, so if it is I would search for a way to bypass it (which I *think* can be done).  Note that Objectify exposes [an API to use the cache manually](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/MemcacheStandalone) if you want, too.  Also, [the last question in their FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Can_I_mix_Low_Level_and_Objectify_writes_in_a_single_Objectify_t) may interest to you.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks, I've got an answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502877/evict-objects-from-objectify-cache/24503527#24503527
and I filed a bug
http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/issues/detail?id=213&thanks=213&ts=1404191909

Comment: Especially this note that I copy for people who come to this question: The global cache will remain consistent as long as you obtain the DatastoreService from ofy().getDatastore(); if you get it directly from DatastoreServiceFactory it will bypass Objectify's global (memcache) cache.